# TextGeometry performance in Three.js

Tags: javascript, performance, text, 3d, three.js

I need to have more than ~400 text objects on the scene. Each text object is one sentence of a decimal number with two digit. Echa text is reading from a JSON file. Each text object have a position (x,y,z) in the scene.

Using a basic scene i'm having, it takes a lot of times to load each text.

The code is here:

```
function setText(text, textColor, textSize, positionX, positionY, positionZ) {        
    var  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
        height: 0,
        curveSegments: 4,
        font: "helvetiker",
        //font: "optimer",
        weight: "normal",
        style: "normal",
        size: textSize,
        //
        //bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
        //bevelSize: bevelSize,
        //bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled,
        material: 0,
        extrudeMaterial: 1
    });

    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
    textGeo.computeVertexNormals();

    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
        shading: THREE.FlatShading, 
        transparent: true,
        depthWrite: false,
        transparent: true,
        needsUpdate: true,
        color: textColor, 
        side:THREE.DoubleSide
    }); 

    var text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);
    text.position.x = positionX;
    text.position.y = positionY;
    text.position.z = positionZ;
    return text;
}
```

Examples of texts:

```
"model", "metamodel", "syntax", "sentence" ...
```

Examples of numbers:

```
    7.32, 
    7.81, 
    8.30, 
    8.78,
```

Could you please help me? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The new code is here :

```
    function createTextGeo(textSize, text) {
        var tGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
            height: 0,
            curveSegments: 4,
            font: "helvetiker",
            weight: "normal",
            style: "normal",
            size: textSize,
            material: 0,
            extrudeMaterial: 1
        });

        tGeo.computeBoundingBox();
        tGeo.computeVertexNormals();
        return tGeo;
    }

    function createGeoMaterial(textColor) {
        var tMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: textColor,
        });
        return tMat;
    }

    function setText(text, textColor, tMat, tGeo, X, Y, Z) {
        tMat.color = textColor;
        tGeo.text = text;

        var text = new THREE.Mesh(tGeo, tMat);
        text.position.set( X, Y, Z );
        return text;
    }

    function createTexts(value) {
        var text;
        var mesh;
        var x = 5;
        var y = 8;
        var z = 10;
        var keyColor = new THREE.Color('#0B0B61');
        var tMat = createGeoMaterial(keyColor);
        var tGeo = createTextGeo(5, "");

        for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            mesh = setText(i, keyColor, tMat, tGeo, x * i, y * i, z * i);
            scene.add(mesh);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either way you will have issues  as you are computing a lot of geometry, look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/million_letters.html

Comment: you could also just separate your json file and load what you only need at the time it needed, Optimize and prioritize...

Comment: @Careen i'm tryng to optimize and prioritize my code, but numbers and texts are part of scales into a graph. Are you another idea ?

Comment: computing a lot of geometry""  look at sharing material not creating a new instance for each text

Comment: @Careen could you be more precise. Maybe if you write me a little example. could you recover some part of my code ? Thanks

Comment: From what im seeing you are creating a new instance of material each time put it outside the function = new material! also i dont think you need doubl sided  material and turn some of them flags off if you dont need them

Comment: @Careen i edit my question with a new code, but the texts are not visualize on the scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76476/discussion-between-careen-and-user3410517).